# Official sbt [maven] set up for rosjava

Tags: ros, gradle, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been struggling setting up Scala access to ROS.  This should normally work via rosjava, but I am struggling with build dependencies.  This is the key part of the build.sbt file regarding rosjava:

```
  resolvers += "rosjava repository" at "https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master",
  resolvers += "jfrog repo" at "https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-releases/",

  libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.6" % "test",
  libraryDependencies += "org.ros.rosjava_core" % "rosjava" % "[0.3,0.4)",
```

the rosjava maven repo is more or less standard following the maven setup suggestions online.  But the build fails (on some commons packages) if I don't include the jfrog repo.  I have no idea what is the jfrog repo, whether it is reliable and will be around to stay.  Is this repo the right way to set up rosjava dependencies? What otherwise? I suppose that any rosjava expert using maven or gradle, will also be able to answer this question.  You don't need to be a Scala/Sbt user.  Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257268/official-sbt-%5Bmaven%5D-set-up-for-rosjava/) by [Andrzej Wasowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/29731/andrzej-wasowski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Half a year later I no longer have the problems.  I use the following sbt setup re. basic Ros Java (build.sbt):

```
  ...
  resolvers += "rosjava repository" at "https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master",
  libraryDependencies += "org.ros.rosjava_core" % "rosjava" % "[0.3,0.4)",
  libraryDependencies += "org.ros.rosjava_messages" % "sensor_msgs" % "[1.12, 1.13)",
  ...
```

The reference to jfrog seems to no longer be needed.

---

Originally posted by [Andrzej Wasowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/29731/andrzej-wasowski/) with karma: 36 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1